# Como mostrar un formulario modal en SEMANTIC UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, semantic-ui

Tengo un botón en el formulario de información o ayuda (el boton rojo con la "i")
[image: boton rojo]

estoy con semantic ui y segun la documentación puedo generar un modal definiendo lo siguiente:

```
<div class="ui modal">
   <i class="close icon"></i>
   <div class="header">
      Modal Title
   </div>
   <div class="image content">
     <div class="image">
         An image can appear on left or an icon
     </div>
    <div class="description">
       A description can appear on the right
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="actions">
    <div class="ui button">Cancel</div>
    <div class="ui button">OK</div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

ese seria el contenido del modal... mientras debo definir

```
     $('.ui.modal')
       .modal()
     ;
```

ahora bien... no se como enlazar el boton (supongamos que tiene como id="ayuda") al evento de hacer clic en el para mostrar ese mensaje modal...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta que usas jQuery para Semantic, puedes usar [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) para abrir la ventana modal:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#abrir_modal').click(function(){
    $('.ui.modal').modal('show');
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.11/semantic.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.11/semantic.js"></script>
<div class="ui modal">
   <i class="close icon"></i>
   <div class="header">
      Modal Title
   </div>
   <div class="image content">
     <div class="image">
         An image can appear on left or an icon
     </div>
    <div class="description">
       A description can appear on the right
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="actions">
    <div class="ui button">Cancel</div>
    <div class="ui button">OK</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <button id="abrir_modal">Abrir modal</button>
```

Comment: Shaz, un maestro !!! necesito tener tu numero de whatsapp !!! jajajajaja

Comment: como corolario: como hago para tener varios textos diferentes para distintas ayudas ? porque si tengo un boton numero dos siempre me va a abrir <div class="ui modal">

Comment: Agrega un id o una clase que haga único cada modal.

Comment: en el <div class="ui modal ayuda1"> <div class="ui modal ayuda2"> etc... y lo llamaría en el script como $('.ui.modal.ayuda1').modal('show'); $('.ui.modal.ayuda2').modal('show'); etc ?

Comment: Los llamarías .ui.ayuda1 y .ui.ayuda2 por ejemplo